# Why does my anonymous function not have the context of the current object in this example?

Tags: javascript

When I run this sample code in Google Chrome, the intended behavior--loading an image within a placeholder image tag on the current page--does not occur.  I checked the value of currPic when showPic() is called, and it is "undefined."  I know if I change the parameter to showPic from 'anchors[i]' to 'this', then it will work, but was trying to understand why this is so.

```
function showPic(currPic) {
    var srcLoc = currPic.getAttribute("href");
    var placeHolder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
    placeHolder.setAttribute("src", srcLoc);
    var imgLabel = document.getElementById("imglabel");
    var currLinkTitle = currPic.getAttribute("title");
    imgLabel.firstChild.nodeValue = currLinkTitle;
}

function prepareGallery() {
    if(!(document.getElementsByTagName && document.getElementById)) return false;

    var imgGallery = document.getElementById("imagegallery");

    if(imgGallery) {
        var anchors = imgGallery.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            anchors[i].onclick = function() {
                showPic(anchors[i]);
                return false;
        }  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the anonymous function, anchors[i] provides a runtime reference. At the time the click occurs, `anchors[i]` no longer exists. While it existed at the time the assignment was made, it falls out of scope at the time of the click (since it's just an array reference). However, using `this` provides a solid reference to the immediate object that is always available at the time of the click.

More succinctly, `anchors[i]` is a reference to a position in an array (which leaves scope once the for loop exits). `this` is a reference to the dom element itself.

Comment: Having a "duh" moment, here.  This is perfectly clear and should have been obvious to me.  Many thanks for this nice explanation, Joel.

Comment: @FabrizioMachado `showPic(anchors[i]);` would also have worked if you have declared `anchors` as a global variable (without the var prefix) - they never go out of scope...

Answer (score 0):

Because this would also work: `showPic(document.getElementById(anchors[i].id));` - do you "get" it now (pun very much intended)?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see the obvious statement regarding how closures work, so here's my take on it.

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].onclick = function() {
        showPic(anchors[i]);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Notice how you reference the `i` variable inside the loop? By the end of your loop, the value of `i` equals `anchors.length`.

So, when *any* of your `onclick` function is executed, that reference to `i` now points one position past the last index of `anchors`; this is why you see `currPic` is `undefined`.

One solution to this problem has been given in other answers: use `this` to reference the current anchor and don't pass `anchors[i]` to the `onclick` function.

As you may encounter similar situations, I'll show you another solution by closing over the value of `i` like so:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].onclick = (function(i) {
        // inside this function, i is closed over and won't change anymore
        return function() {
            showPic(anchors[i]);
            return false;
        }
    }(i));
}
```